# How do I reload data in my TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I've seen some answers on Stack about this question but a lot of them are from 5 years ago and using an older version of Swift. I would like to reload the data in the table every time the user hits save so that the appended event will now be added to the table. But no matter what I seem to do nothing is showing up!
I've tried adding `table.reloadData()` in my save function. But i get an error for:

> Thread 1 error, Fatal error: unexpectedly found a nil while unwrapping an optional value.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLocation: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTime: UITextField!

    var eventsArray = [Event]()

    @IBAction func btnSave() {
        let event = Event(tits: txtTitle.text!, locs: txtLocation.text!)

        eventsArray.append(event)
        table.reloadData()
        print(eventsArray)

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomeCell

        cell.title.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].title
        cell.location.text = eventsArray[indexPath.row].location

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to reload the table?

Comment: i kept getting errors from trying table.reloadData()

Comment: Show the code where you tried it and show what "errors" you got.

Comment: [Edit] your question with what you have tried and the error message.

Comment: I'm betting that `@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!` is `nil` because you forgot to hook up the outlet from the table view in the storyboard.

Comment: @matt i checked i hooked up the outlets in the main storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: so at the line table.reloadData() i have an optional value that I'm forcefully unwrapping which is saying that there is nothing being stored in my event? @rmaddy>?

Comment: No, `table` *must* be `nil` here because `event` isn't an optional, and `table` is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional.  Double-check your outlet again.

Comment: table views outlet is hooked up to the view controller

Comment: On which line exactly does Xcode throw this error?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh the line that i call table.reloadData()

Comment: Wait, you're still having troubles with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set tableView's delegate on viewDidLoad?

```
table.delegate = self
```